# How to update a title's position in matplotlib when it has been drawn already

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, formatting, overlap

I'm trying to automatically move matplotlib `Text` instances above some annotations which are not taken into account by `plt.tight_layout` or `constrained_layout`.

However, I can't seem to get the title positions to update using `Text.set_position` and redrawing afterwards (neither when using e.g. `fig.canvas.draw()` every update nor when calling `title_text_instance.draw(renderer=fig.canvas.get_renderer())`).

The text itself seems to update fine, and so does another annotation, which is weird as both title and annotation are `Text` objects.

Why doesn't the title position update in the code below?

Animation for illustration; the title text and annotation positions update as expected, but its position remains fixed:

[image: Title text and annotation positions update as expected, but its position remains fixed.k]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

N_FRAMES: int = 10
# Setting up the example.
mpl.use("TkAgg")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 1), dpi=300)
ax.plot(range(10), range(10))
t = ax.set_title("Example title", fontsize=6, alpha=.8, clip_on=False)

atext1 = '\n'.join(['Overlapping extra-axis annotation',
                    'above which I want to move the title',
                    'undetected by tight_layout or constrained_layout'])
atext2 = 'this annotation moves just fine...'
a1 = ax.annotate(atext1, xycoords='axes fraction', xy=(.25, 1),
                 rotation=10, clip_on=False, fontsize=3, color='r', alpha=.6)
a2 = ax.annotate(atext2, xycoords='axes fraction', xy=(.5, .5),
                 clip_on=False, fontsize=4, color='g')
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.tight_layout()
# ^^ Leaving out plt.tight_layout doesn't
# make a difference w.r.t position updates

for yoffset in range(N_FRAMES):
    new_position = (t.get_position()[0], t.get_position()[1] - .5 + (yoffset / 2))
    newpostext = '(' + ', '.join(f'{pos:.2f}' for pos in new_position) + ')'

    # Changing positions
    print(f'Set new position to', newpostext)
    t.set_position(new_position)  # Doesn't work
    a2.set_position(new_position)  # Works fine

    t.set_text(f"Supposedly repositioned title position: \n (x, y) = {newpostext}")
    plt.pause(.5)

plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.resizable(False, False)
plt.show(block=False)
plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal property `_autotitlepos` for the title which is [set to `True` unless you explicitly specify the y position of the title](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/dae28c61ed255c9b75b7c7fb2689777d90f5b72e/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L145-L148). So in order to be able to manually set the title position you need to supply a value for `y` when setting the title, e.g. the default value of `1`:

```
t = ax.set_title("Example title", fontsize=6, alpha=.8, clip_on=False, y=1)
```

(minimum matplotlib version 3.3.0, see [PR #17127](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17127))